# Lazy Loading a Grid View - Huge number of records binding

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

In the page load , i need to bind a grid view with approximately 2 lakh records. I have perform operations like edit and delete in the grid view.

here, my problem is the page is taking too much time to load because of huge number of records.

So , probably the solution would be lazy loading . But , i was not sure of how to implement it. I guess one of ways of doing it is by advanced sorting.

Is there any other method to accomplish this by ajax or etc. Please suggest me an idea how can i achieve this?

and one more doubt whether it is possible to sort and filter grid when we are lazy loading?

Please help me on this ang give your valuble suggestions for me to implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Paging.  Only retrieve one page at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Can we able to sort and filter grid when we are loading page by page?

Comment: Yes. You apply sort order before your technique of selecting the page.